# ArrayList.size() is not working

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist

I am practicing for google kick start. There i found this question for practise https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/9234486/dashboard.
I made the following code till now but it is not working.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numOfCases = 0, numOfSteps = 0, num = 0;
        ArrayList<Integer> indexOfOdd = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        String input = "";
        boolean isOdd = false;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        numOfCases = in.nextInt();
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= numOfCases ; i++) {
            input = in.next();
            for(int j = 0; j<input.length(); j++) {
                num=Integer.parseInt(input.substring(j,j+1));
                if (num%2!=0) {
                    indexOfOdd.add(j);
                }
                System.out.println(indexOfOdd);
            }
            if(indexOfOdd.size() == 0) {
                numOfSteps = 1;
            }
            indexOfOdd.clear();
            System.out.println("Case #" + i + ": " + numOfSteps);
            }
    }
}
```

This was my output file :

```
[]
[]
Case #1: 1
[0]
[0, 1]
Case #2: 1
[0]
Case #3: 1
[]
[]
[2]
[2]
Case #4: 1
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
Case #5: 1
[]
Case #6: 1
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 3]
[0, 1, 3, 4]
Case #7: 1
[]
[]
[]
[]
[4]
Case #8: 1
[0]
Case #9: 1
[]
[1]
[1]
[1]
[1]
Case #10: 1
[]
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 4]
Case #11: 1
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
Case #12: 1
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
Case #13: 1
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
Case #14: 1
[]
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
Case #15: 1
[]
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
Case #16: 1
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
Case #17: 1
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0, 3]
[0, 3]
Case #18: 1
[0]
[0]
[0, 2]
[0, 2]
[0, 2, 4]
Case #19: 1
[0]
[0]
[0, 2]
[0, 2, 3]
[0, 2, 3]
Case #20: 1
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
Case #21: 1
[]
[1]
[1]
[1, 3]
[1, 3]
Case #22: 1
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
Case #23: 1
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 4]
Case #24: 1
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2]
Case #25: 1
[]
[]
[2]
[2, 3]
[2, 3]
Case #26: 1
[]
[]
[]
[3]
[3, 4]
Case #27: 1
[]
Case #28: 1
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
Case #29: 1
[]
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
Case #30: 1
[0]
Case #31: 1
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 3]
[0, 1, 3, 4]
Case #32: 1
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
Case #33: 1
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
Case #34: 1
[0]
[0]
Case #35: 1
[0]
[0, 1]
Case #36: 1
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
Case #37: 1
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
Case #38: 1
[]
[]
[2]
[2]
[2, 4]
Case #39: 1
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
Case #40: 1
[]
[1]
[1]
[1]
Case #41: 1
[]
[]
[2]
[2]
[2]
Case #42: 1
[0]
[0]
[0, 2]
[0, 2]
[0, 2]
Case #43: 1
[]
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
Case #44: 1
[]
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
Case #45: 1
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
Case #46: 1
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 4]
Case #47: 1
[0]
[0]
[0, 2]
[0, 2, 3]
[0, 2, 3, 4]
Case #48: 1
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
Case #49: 1
[]
Case #50: 1
[]
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
Case #51: 1
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0, 4]
Case #52: 1
[0]
[0, 1]
Case #53: 1
[0]
Case #54: 1
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 4]
Case #55: 1
[]
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
Case #56: 1
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
Case #57: 1
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 3]
[0, 1, 3, 4]
Case #58: 1
[]
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 4]
Case #59: 1
[]
[1]
[1]
[1, 3]
[1, 3, 4]
Case #60: 1
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
Case #61: 1
[]
[1]
[1]
[1, 3]
[1, 3]
Case #62: 1
[]
[1]
[1]
[1, 3]
[1, 3]
Case #63: 1
[0]
[0]
[0, 2]
[0, 2, 3]
[0, 2, 3, 4]
Case #64: 1
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0, 4]
Case #65: 1
[]
[]
[2]
[2]
[2, 4]
Case #66: 1
[]
[1]
[1]
[1]
[1]
Case #67: 1
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
Case #68: 1
[]
[]
[2]
[2]
[2, 4]
Case #69: 1
[]
[1]
[1]
[1]
[1]
Case #70: 1
[]
[1]
[1]
[1]
[1, 4]
Case #71: 1
[0]
Case #72: 1
[0]
[0]
[0, 2]
[0, 2]
[0, 2, 4]
Case #73: 1
[]
[]
[2]
[2]
[2]
Case #74: 1
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
Case #75: 1
[]
[1]
[1]
[1]
Case #76: 1
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
Case #77: 1
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 4]
Case #78: 1
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2]
Case #79: 1
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0, 3]
[0, 3, 4]
Case #80: 1
[0]
[0]
[0, 2]
[0, 2]
[0, 2]
Case #81: 1
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0, 3]
Case #82: 1
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
Case #83: 1
[0]
[0]
[0, 2]
[0, 2]
[0, 2]
Case #84: 1
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
Case #85: 1
[]
Case #86: 1
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 4]
Case #87: 1
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
Case #88: 1
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
Case #89: 1
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 4]
Case #90: 1
[]
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
Case #91: 1
[]
[]
[2]
[2]
[2, 4]
Case #92: 1
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 3]
[0, 1, 3, 4]
Case #93: 1
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
Case #94: 1
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
Case #95: 1
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
Case #96: 1
[]
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
Case #97: 1
[]
[]
[]
[]
[4]
Case #98: 1
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2]
Case #99: 1
[0]
[0]
[0, 2]
[0, 2]
[0, 2, 4]
Case #100: 1
```

Please help me. I am confused that which part is not working. It should work like if the array list is empty it should show 1 else 0. So what is the error????

I am just a student studying in 12th grade in India so I would appreciate the elaboration of the errors found.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fIVWsMXVJLknmlzkNE_2iQakW-nsMRXJ

This are the files you can view them for reference.
Thanks.

Comment: Why would it show 0?  You never change it from 1.

Comment: initially it was 0 so why should it change of 1 for every case when I applied if

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] using constants instead of a `Scanner` to be able to see what is happening with specific values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You expect the value `numOfSteps` to be at zero in some cases but since you don't reset the value for each inputs, once you have values in the list once, every other test are incorrect. You simply need to set the variable to zero based on the condition :

```
if(indexOfOdd.size() == 0) {
    numOfSteps = 1;
} else {
    numOfSteps = 0;
}
```

Or using a ternary :

```
numOfSteps = indexOfOdd.size() == 0 ? 1 : 0;
```

You can also reset `numOfSteps` at zero at the beginning of each iteration.

```
for (int i = 1 ; i <= numOfCases ; i++) {
    numOfSteps  = 0;
    input = in.next();
    ...
```

EDIT:

You could be interested by the `List.isEmpty` method that return a boolean.

```
numOfSteps = indexOfOdd.isEmpty() ? 0 : 1;
```

Comment: Thanks It is working now. I think in the first iteration when the size was 0 it was assigning it 1  and then never changing it on updation so every thing was 1.

Comment: Indeed @NischayaSharma, that's what I explained. You are expecting the variable to be at zero but never write a single case where you set it at zero... that was your problem and you have above 2 solutions. PS: I have edited the solution adding a method that could be interesting.

Comment: Hmm isEmpty is nice Thanks

Comment: Hey @AlexH can you please go to my output file and check some results are repeating for some 4 to 5 consecutive inputs then giving correct result for 2 to 3 inputs and then again giving same result for next 4 to 5 inputs. The link is in the question. My code is also in the same folder.

Comment: Well @NischayaSharma , all you do is to count the number of odd digit but that's not what is asked. You need to count the number of "increment" or "decrement" needed to only get even number. So if wouo have 13, you will need 5 decrements to get to 8. (because 1# have a 1 that is odd).

Comment: ok so what i am thinking is just take the first digit of the number if it is even then the we just round down to number to that even digit and if it is odd then round it up to the next even number like 1932 will be 2000 and 2932 will also be 2000.

Comment: Well, that's what the second case seems to proove : "_In Sample Case #2 (11), pressing the minus button three times will cause the calculator to display 8. There is no way to satisfy the requirements with fewer than three button presses._"

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
numOfSteps = indexOfOdd.size();
```

instead of

```
if(indexOfOdd.size() == 0) {
  numOfSteps = 1;
}
```

Your modified method will be as follows.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numOfCases = 0, numOfSteps = 0, num = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> indexOfOdd = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    String input = "";
    in = new Scanner(System.in);
    numOfCases = in.nextInt();
    for (int i = 1; i <= numOfCases; i++) {
        input = in.next();
        for (int j = 0; j < input.length(); j++) {
            num = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(j, j + 1));
            if (num % 2 != 0) {
                indexOfOdd.add(j);
            }
            System.out.println(indexOfOdd);
        }

        numOfSteps = indexOfOdd.size();

        indexOfOdd.clear();
        System.out.println("Case #" + i + ": " + numOfSteps);
    }
}
```

Comment: You realize that ternary don't make sense ? `indexOfOdd.size() > 0 ? indexOfOdd.size() : 0;` ... just set `indexOfOdd.size()` then since it can't be negative.

Comment: Thanks @AxelH. no need to use ternary operator.